# NextGen open album directly in lightbox

Tags: wordpress, gallery

a new recent update to the nextgen plugin to 2.0.14 was added on August 27, 2013.

I was wondering if it's possible when a user clicks on an album thumbnail instead of it going to a specific gallery page, the lightbox would popup instead and show the images related to that gallery. The plugin used to have a gallery option that says: The album will not link to a gallery subpage. The gallery is shown on the same page. But after the update I can't find it anymore and I'm not if it's removed.

I used to use this method http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-nextgen-gallery-nextgen-gallery-open-album-in-lightbox but the newst update of nextgen completely removed my lightbox styles/settings and now it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue, and I used the exact same method you referenced. I've been working on a solution and am about 95% of the way there.

To retain my custom template, I used some of the information (through "Customising for a theme") from here: http://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/creating-a-custom-gallery-template-for-nextgen-gallery/ -

1. create the folder “nggallery” inside the theme folder
2. copy the file “album-lightbox.php” from NextGEN’s “view” folder to the new “nggallery” folder

Essentially, I moved my album-lightbox.php file (which I created via the method you referenced) into an "nggallery" folder in my theme folder. I did NOT rename the album-lightbox.php file, however.

I did have some custom CSS that needed to be updated to overwrite some of their new CSS.

I was having an issue with the thumbnail size for gallery image. You can modify the thumbnail size when you insert an Extended Album into a page:

> You'd need to go to a page / post, either add or edit an Extended Album, then click the accordion to "Customize" the display type, select to override thumbnail dimensions, then set your custom thumbnail dimensions there.

More on that here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/nextgen-2014-no-activation-because-of-a-fatal-error?replies=5#post-4600965

The only issue I'm still having with the thumbnail images for the galleries is that I can't modify the thumbnail itself, like I used to be able to in Manage Galleries > [gallery] > [hover over image] Edit thumb. Any changes I make there don't carry over to the image displayed for the gallery itself. The gallery appears to simply be center-cropping (horizontal and vertical) the image chosen to be the preview.

That is probably not a deal-breaker for a lot of folks however!